# Strange C2065 error in extern library

Tags: c++, c, namespaces, declaration

I have an extern code written in C in my C++ project in MS VS 2010. It comes with .h and .c files and I use include like this:

```
extern "C"{
#include "Extern\libname.h"
}
```

It worked nice. Then I read  [Google C++ style guide](http://google-styleguide.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/cppguide.xml) and removed all entries of

```
using namespace std;
```

replaced them with just

```
std::whatINeed
```

everywhere.

And the error showed up -

```
error C2065: 'FILE' : undeclared identifier
```

in the header of extern library. And then I move cursor to the word "FILE" in that code, there is

```
tydef _iobuf FILE
```

What should I add into my code to fix it? I don't want to change extern code because it can be updated and I will be forced to add my fixes on every update. Also, I am sure that there is a simple bug caused by me.

Comment: Nope, I extremely don't want to change that lib.

Comment: Something somewhere wants to use old C "streams", you need to find the place in your source and either rewrite it or include `<stdio.h>`.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg Can you please help me to find out what are old "C" streams look like?

Comment: The are using `FILE` pointers as returned by `fopen`. Just do a search through all your files for e.g. `FILE` or `fopen`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add

```
#include <cstdio>
```

above you include.